# SQL Server 2005 - String Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, string-concatenation

I have a table that looks like below (Before) and using SQL I would like to make it the same as the table shown in 'After'.

Image here:

[image]

How would this be possible in SQL Server?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you want to store data this way? So that when you want to search for `Terry` it is really hard?

Comment: Don't use screenshots to provide your schema but add it to your question. That has three advantages: 1. we can see it without clicking on links 2. we are able to see it even if the image provider doesn't exist anymore 3. we are able to create sample-data on sql-fiddle

Comment: @Tim and 4. I know of at least one user for whom `imgur.com` is blocked, so they can't see it today either.